# Should I re-throw an exception after logging it?

Tags: java, exception

I find myself coding methods that throw a specified error, but still surrounding the relevant code sections in a try catch, where I use the catch to log a localised error message and re-throw the principal one.

Here is a short example:

```
public void doWork(String url) throws IOException {
    Object target;
    try {
        target = new target(url);  //instantiating this object could potentially not work if the URL is malformed
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        localErrorMessage(debug, "URL error here");  //log a local message
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {  //in some cases it can throw an IO exception if using a localised file type object.
        localErrorMessage(debug, "IO error here");  //log a local message           throw e;
    }
}
```

I use this as I can turn off my localised logging (using log4j2), or use it during testing, as a debugging method.

Is this a reasonable practice, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What does `localErrorMessage` do? (Usually Java methods -- methods in general, really -- should be verbs, as they're actions.) Does it actually throw an IO error? If not, `doWork` never throws an IO error, and so the signature is misleading. Or actually, looking at the `catch` above it, maybe you're missing a `throw e;` there?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `MalformedURLException` extends `IOException`. The method can throw one.

Comment: If you are set on rethowing `e`, consider wrapping it in a new exception with some useful info. Maybe something like `throw new IOException(e, url + " is not valid");`

Comment: @bradimus: Ah, yes, well-spotted on the subclass.

Comment: So this is a rather contrived, oversimplified example, I'm just using it to better show what I mean in my question, in case it isn't clear  . The `object target` when constructed does a load of strange stuff, and this is where the thrown errors are handled with extended error messaging. the `localErrorMessage` is for simple localised debug.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder regarding the IOException. Strangely I found during testing that the method could throw either a MalFormedURL or an IO. So I needed a way to handle either, but the IO is much more basic (mostly network related), which I will have to deal with eventually in the UI I guess, but the MALformedURL can be handled differently (and immediately).

Comment: You should rethrow the exception of he *caller* cares about it. If the *caller* doesn#t care, then why bother throwing it? If the *caller* cares, then rethroing is appropriate. the other way to notify the caller would be to return an object that represents an error state, but wether or not thats good design is debatable. Anyways, this isn#t a good Q&A, because there is no right answer.

Comment: I think generally, you should not throw an exception again after the catch. If you need to catch it in somewhere else then you should not catch it in this place.

Comment: I would think the reason the exception has a stacktrace is so you don't have to do this kind of thing. Maybe you don't trust the application to not eat the exceptions before they get to the main exception handler?